# How to enable WS-A Addressing on my JAX-WS generated client code

Tags: jax-ws, wsimport, addressing

I would like to access a third party websevice using a Java client that I generated with JAX-WS wsimport, based on the WSDL provided (I am using a Maven plugin).

For quite a while I was unable to retrieve a useful response, not in the Java client and also not in SoapUI, until I found out that I had to enable WS-A on the request. 
In SoapUI this now results in the expected response, but what must I do to also 'enable' WS-A in the Java client? Do I maybe have to alter the WSDL, or add a parameter to wsimport?

I found some documentation on WS-A online, but so far could not find an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the WSDL as you mentioned, to indicate addressing is required (though I would ask the 3rd party to, if their endpoint truly requires it..).  See example 3-1 and 3-2 on [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-wsdl/) for this.  You may need to regenerate your client (wsimport); of this I am not sure.

If you want to accomplish this programmatically, you can try obtaining your port and passing a `javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature` as follows:

```
import javax.xml.ws.soap.AddressingFeature;
...
//however you are obtaining your service - 
//perhaps @WebServiceRef or instantiation with WSDL location, etc
HelloWorldService service = ... 
...
//true,true means enable Addressing, and indicate it is required
HelloWorld port = service.getHelloWorldPort(new AddressingFeature(true, true));
... call operations/methods on HelloWorld port
```

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/soap/AddressingFeature.html) for AddressingFeature may yield more insight as well.

Comment: Thanks @scotth, this is now clear to me and it saved me a lot of time. I have asked the providing party to alter their WSDL accordingly, they agreed to do so. I'll mark it as answered, although I am now facing another problem which I posted here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705383/jax-ws-adds-namespace-in-signature-of-token)